# Helpers in Rails 5 API Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5 in API mode seems not to support helpers.

```
rails new myapp --api
```

does not create the app/helpers folder.

How do we use the helpers in Rails 5 API mode?

Comment: why not create it yourself? Rails should autoload everything under `app/`

Comment: I did try creating app/helpers folder and adding the helper module. Rails 5 autoload ignores app/helpers folder in API mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature of Rails 5 has removed a lot of folders that are not required for the application.

Please go through the deep details about the API-Mode in Rails 5....

[Refere Here](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/how-to-make-rails-5-api-only)

Comment: I did end up adding the helper methods to the controller, which works just fine. I am not sure about the best practices when it comes to helper methods in Rails 5 API model.

Comment: To achieve similar functionality to that of helper methods in Rails 5 API-only applications, I'm a big fan of creating application-specific libraries.  You would want to create a module or class inside your lib directory and then include/extend or require it elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
 config.generators.helper = true
```

in

```
 config/application.rb
```

Then when you generate controllers you will get helpers also